# Why am i returning this syntax error in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax, group-by

I am new to SQL and coding in general. I am not finding the syntax error in this.

```
SELECT t1.artist, t1.year, t2.total
FROM tutorial.billboard_top_100_year_end AS 't1'
  JOIN (SELECT billboard_top_100_year_end.artist, COUNT(*) AS 'total'
    FROM tutorial.billboard_top_100_year_end
    GROUP BY year) AS 't2'
  ON t1.artist = t2.artist AND t1.total = t2.total
WHERE artist LIKE 'Elvis%'
LIMIT 100;
```

This results in

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "'t1'"
>     Position: 149
>   SELECT t1.artist, t1.year, t2.total
>   FROM tutorial.billboard_top_100_year_end AS 't1'
>                                               ^
>     JOIN (SELECT billboard_top_100_year_end.artist, COUNT(*) AS 'total'

Before this i was receiving the error

> ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

and made adjustments to address this

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `'t2'` in the derived table.  This is a misuse of quotes, and I vote to close as a typo.

Comment: Your group by seems incorrect. The group by error is because you're selecting the `artist` column along with count. try `group by billboard_top_100_year_end.artist` instead of `year`. If you want to also group by year, you can but that's not why the error was thrown. I also agree with the comment to remove quotes from `t2` as they are not needed.

Comment: `AS 'total'` is invalid (standard) SQL - which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I am using mode

my entry is now: 
`SELECT t1.artist, t1.year, t2.total
FROM tutorial.billboard_top_100_year_end AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT artist, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM tutorial.billboard_top_100_year_end
    GROUP BY billboard_top_100_year_end.artist) AS t2
  ON t1.artist = t2.artist AND total = t2.total
WHERE artist LIKE 'Elvis%'
ORDER BY year
LIMIT 100;`

>ERROR: column reference "artist" is ambiguous
  Position: 346
  ON t1.artist = t2.artist AND total = t2.total
WHERE artist LIKE 'Elvis%'
      ^
ORDER BY year

Comment: Also worth mentioning i am learning on SQLite. I understand there are some differences

Comment: `where t1.artist like 'Elvis%'`